# Codeigniter: routing format "controller/method" not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Honestly, i have been working with codeigniter framework since 1 year and had no problems till now. I downloaded codeigniter 3.1.3 and set it up on RHEL6.8 64 bit OS on a LAMPP stack. I am not sure what has changed in the newer version of codeigniter, but it seems that the default routing way of "controller/method" is not working.

The new routing format accepts in the form **?c=profile&userId=1**.

How do i change the routing format to "**controller/method**"?

And what are the benefits and drawbacks between the 2 routing formats?

Answer (score 0):

See `application/config/config.php` .

Just change

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

TO

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

The configuration item `enable_query_strings` is used to `enable/disable` query strings.

Comment: I just tried toggling the value of enable_query_strings in config.php from TRUE to FALSE like you mentioned but now the controller is not getting detected.. It just says 404 not found, even though clearly there is a controller.. And the query strings are getting ignored when i submit a form.. Please suggest..